# cannot concatenate 'str' and 'instance' objects

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

i'm coding a program, that, if you put a text in a textbox it search the content on Google.com, but it returns an error:

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'instance' objects
```

This is the code:

```
InputStrings = StringVar()
    Entry(root, textvariable = InputStrings).pack()

def OutputText():
    OutStrings = InputStrings.get()
    b = "https://www.google.it/search?q="
    if InputStrings:
        b = b + InputStrings
    webbrowser.open(b)
    root.withdraw()
    root.quit()
```

Answer (score 6):

The error is in the line

```
b = b + InputStrings
```

As InputStrings is a StringVar object, and b is a string, you cannot add them together. You probably meant to use

```
b = b + OutStrings
```

As OutStrings is a string that you have created via InputStrings.get(), so you can add it to another string freely. "Concatenation" essentially means "String addition" in this case.